# PayPal cURL options (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST) issue

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I've got a piece of code from the PayPal site:

```
// turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
// really paypal??? why not just include a recent cert???
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

As you can see in my comment I'm wondering why on earth paypal would disable those options.

I know (from previous headaches :) ) that on Windows cURL uses an outdated certs file.

But I have a newer certs file on my server which I could just use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'E:\path\to\curl-ca-bundle.crt');
```

So why would PayPal 'recommend' disabling it if all it takes is use another (newer) certs file.

Wouldn't that be safer?

Or am I missing something (I'm pretty sure PayPal has enough money for a valid certificate :p )?

Comment: "on Windows cURL uses an outdated certs file" is plain wrong. curl doesn't ship any CA cert bundle at all, so the responsibility to have an updated one falls on the user...

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg: OK It's been a while since I had to use cURL on Windows. Well cURL used to ship with an out outdated cert bundle until 7.18.0 (January 28 2008 I know). :) And you know it...

Comment: You're right. My wording was sloppy as I should probably have mentioned that several years ago curl _did_ ship a CA cert bundle... Sorry, and thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @DanielStenberg: Thank yourself. Wouldn't surprise me if I got my info from you @ curl.haxx.se :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it would be much safer to make sure clients use an updated CA cert bundle. (Which this question is about, they already have a certificate.)

Answer (score 4):

One reason could be that it prevents support headaches, with people running the script on their $1 / year shared hosting boxes, running into issues, etc.
Best practice? No. But someone with a bit more knowledge beside ctrl+c ctrl+v will be able to set it up properly.

**edit:** our current sample code forces VERIFYPEER and VERIFYHOST. Keep this in mind if you run into any SSL handshake errors, as you may need to point to a root cert file copy.